# WPF Style Trigger not working with custom Enum

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-style

Hello I wonder why my Style Trigger not working depend on custom enum? The code is below:

```
   <Style x:Key="FontAwesomeIconBase"
          BasedOn="{StaticResource FontAwesomeFont}"
          TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag}" Value="FontIcon.None">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="FontIcon.None">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="None">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I tried DataTrigger but stil not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope. Actually I tried nearly 10 different combination about the value but it didnt help :)

Comment: You are basically binding to a string in your triggers, you are not telling the where the Enum value should be located.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an xmlns(namespace) reference of Enum(Where it defined) in your Window/UserControl file as write below:

```
xmlns:font="clr-namespace:YourEnumNameSpace"


<DataTrigger Property="Tag" Value="{x:Static font:FontIcon.None}">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

use x:Static keyword with value than your EnumClassName.EnumValue. Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thanks I used your answer but didnt helped. I still see the grid on window

Comment: In that case,Make double sure that your Tag property is binded properly.

Comment: I think you are using ViewModel property so I told you that check your binding but if you want to use UI property than you can use it direct in trigger it works.